# Syncfusion hyperlink in ejgrid column

Tags: syncfusion

Does anyone know how I can add a hyperlink to the Username column in my code below?

```
$("#ManagerApprovalGrid").ejGrid({
                        dataSource: data,
                        isResponsive: true,
                        allowScrolling: true,
                        allowFiltering: true,
                        allowSorting: true,
                        columns: [
                            { field: "userDispName", headerText: 'Timesheet User', textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Left, width: 20}, 
                            { field: "weekEndDate", headerText: 'Week End Date', textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Center, width: 20 }

                        ]

                    });
```

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the below knowledge base to place hyperlink in `ejGrid`.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/3767

**Update**

The ejGrid uses JSRender template to render its content. So you can do like below to pass the parameter to the hyperlink.

```
$("#ManagerApprovalGrid").ejGrid({
                   . . . . . 
                    columns: [
                       { 
                         field: "userDispName", 
                         template:"<a href=something/{{:userDispName}}>View</a>" 
                         headerText: 'Timesheet User',
                         textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Left, width: 20
                      }, 
                       . . . . 

                    ]

                });
```

**Demo:** http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/nvoeeoel

Comment: Would you know how to pass in a parameter with the link? For example :  template: "<a href=#approvals/userDispName>View</a>"